# Trying to return a value in a method created in an object and the method contains for loops and if statements but can't do it

Tags: java, for-loop, oop, if-statement, methods

So I am asked to write a program that reads a sentence from the user, reports and removes wrong repetitions if any. By wrong repetitions I mean that a word (or more) is repeated (two occurrences or more) and that these repetition are consecutive.

`

```
public class checker {
    
    private String sentence;
    
    checker(String sentence){this.sentence=sentence;}
    
    public String check(){
        
        String[] word = sentence.split(" ");
        
        for(int i=0; i<word.length; i++){
            for(int j=i+1; j<word.length; j++){
                if(word[i].equals(word[j])){
                    word[j]="error";}}}
        
        for(int i=0; i<word.length; i++) {
            if (!"error".equals(word[i])) {
                System.out.print(word[i] + " ");}}
        
        return "";}
}
```

***This is the output of my code: ***

Enter a Sentence: The operator did not not skip his meal
The operator did not skip his meal
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 12 seconds)

So my code does the job of finding the repeated words and prints the corrected version, but the problem is that I just can't find a way to make it print out like it is supposed to do in the sample run!

[Sample runs:

-Enter a sentence: The operator did not not skip his meal
-The sentence includes wrong repetitions.
-The sentence should be: The operator did not skip his meal

-Enter a sentence: Happy people live longer
-There are no wrong repetitions]

**I do know my problem, every time I try to write a piece of code containing any time type of loops and if statements together I just don't know to extract what I want from the loop and conditional statements, I was trying to

`

```
for(int i=0; i<word.length; i++){
    for(int j=i+1; j<word.length; j++){
        if(word[i].equals(word[j])){
            System.out.println("The sentence includes wrong repetitions.\nThe sentence should be: ");
            word[j]="error";}
        else{
             System.out.println("There are no wrong repetitions");
            }
    }   
}
```

`
but I know it'll print it every time the loop gets executed!

I would really appreciate a helpful tip that I can carry with me going forward!

Thanks in advance guys!**

Comment: Can you post sample output that you are actually receiving? Eyeballing it, the loops you have confuse me. It seems that your inner loop is not tracking with your outer one. Let's say the sentence is "The cat jumped jumped over the dog." Your loops are going to check the word "The" against every word, and then "cat" against every word and so on. What you want is to check consecutive pairs I believe. Consider setting up one for loop that checks 'i' and 'i+1' perhaps?

Comment: This is my sample run:  
       
Enter a Sentence: The operator did not not skip his meal
The operator did not skip his meal 
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 12 seconds)

Comment: I believe another problem you had in the code above is you are replacing a word with 'error.' If it were me, I would think of a way to shift the words within the array and then build a normal string from the result. Hopefully that makes sense.

Comment: I appreciate the help my friend! I tried coming up with ideas but couldn't, so I stuck with replacing the word with "error" and then using a for loop to rebuild my sentence. The problem is  that I'm not that experienced when it comes to writing code, so a lot of times ideas just fly over my head from inexperience in the field which is something I'm going to work on surely! it does make sense, I'll make sure to think about it for a bit and see what comes up on my mind, again i really appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

You don't have any mechanism by which to store your valid words so you can print them in the format you need to after your sentence evaluation is complete. I recommend storing the valid words in a StringBuilder or ArrayList as you go so you can print the resulting string when you are ready.

Here is a sample program to accomplish this using a StringBuilder. You could also use an ArrayList and call `String.join(" ", wordList);` to create the sentence when finished.

```
final String sentence = "This is an invalid invalid sentence that that needs corrected";
final String[] words = sentence.split(" ");
StringBuilder sentenceBuilder = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++)
{
    final String checkWord = words[i];
    final boolean lastWord = i == words.length - 1;
    final boolean duplicate = !lastWord && checkWord.equals(words[i + 1]);
    if (lastWord || !duplicate)
        sentenceBuilder.append(checkWord);
    if (!lastWord && !duplicate)
        sentenceBuilder.append(' ');
}
if (!sentence.equals(sentenceBuilder.toString()))
    System.out.printf("The sentence includes wrong repetitions.%nThe sentence should be: %s%n", sentenceBuilder);
else
    System.out.println("There are no wrong repetitions");
```

Comment: Thank you, It did solve my problem, but the thing is I am not allowed to use a StringBuilder or String.join(" ", wordList); since the instructor won't let me do so, because we haven't gone over these methods yet. So, that's a bummer! But!!! I still appreciate you for taking from your precious time and helping me out!

Comment: Are you allowed to use a List or ArrayList? If so, just replace the StringBuilder with a List of Strings and then just add them all together at the end. In the future, if you specify the requirements of what you are allowed to use and what you aren't allowed to use in your question it will help get you a better answer.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem in my assignment last week. I couldn't solve it but I had to submit something so I don't get a zero. The errors in my program is that there is a space left in place of the duplicated word, and it only detects two occurrences.

Here's the code i wrote:

```
 String [] n= s.split(" ");
   boolean check=false;
 
   for (int i=1;i<n.length;i++){
       String    temp=n[i-1];
       if (n[i].equals(temp) == true) {
       check = true;
           System.out.println("The sentence includes wrong repetitions.");
     n[i]="";
     System.out.print("The sentence should be: ");
   for(int j=0;j<n.length;j++) {
       System.out.print(n[j]+" ");
       
   }
       }
      
   }
   
   if (check == false)
            System.out.println("There are no wrong repetitions");   
    }
    
}
```

Let me know if you found the solution or if you can improve my code

Comment: Yes! I was able to solve the problem, after hours of staring at my code I noticed a huge mistake that prevented me from using one for-loop which is i<n.length-1 instead of i<n.length !

Comment: the first mistake is i=1 your for-loop starts from i=1 which will start from index 1 not index 0, the for-loop will look much easier if you just write it as for(int i=0; i<word.length-1; i++){
            if(word[i].equals(word[i+1])){
                rep = true;
                word[i+1]="error";}}    
and then after the loop to reconstruct your correct sentence you have to use another loops with an if statement if (!"error".equals(word[i])) 
                    System.out.print(word[i] + " ");  
I hope this'll help you, if not make sure to post it as a problem and i'll write you an ans

Comment: The instructor sent us the solution, here you go for future reference:

Answer (score 0):

The insturctor sent us the solution, adding it here for future reference:

```
/*
```

CSCI300 - Solution of Assignment 1
Problem 2
*/
package repetitions;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Repetitions {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    boolean hasSuccessiveReptition = false; //Assume no repetitions
    
    System.out.print("Enter a sentence: ");
    // Read the whole sentence into one String:
    String sentence = scan.nextLine();
    
    //create an array of Strings to handle each word separately
    String[] words = sentence.split(" ");
    //Create a string to add non repetetive words to
    String repetitionFreeSentence = words[0];  // add the fisrt word

    for(int i = 1; i < words.length; i++)
        if(words[i].equalsIgnoreCase(words[i-1])) // compare successive words
            hasSuccessiveReptition = true;
        else // add the word to the corrected setence
            repetitionFreeSentence += " " + words[i];        
    if(hasSuccessiveReptition){
        System.out.println("The sentence includes wrong repetitions.");
        System.out.println("The sentence should be: " + repetitionFreeSentence);
    }
    else
        System.out.println("There are no wrong repetitions");
}
```

}